Screw in fuse box
I need to replace the piece in fuse box that my 30amp fuse screws into. Can I buy just that? Or have to change the whole thing?

Can you please edit your question and add a photo?

Assuming this is a small(a couple or just a few fuses) secondary fuse box, it might be easier to just replace it with a similar one.  To replace parts you need the make and model numbers and find the parts to replace, probably most of the insides.

Yes, can you get us photos of the fuse box? You may be better off replacing the whole thing with a modern breaker panel

You want what we called a "plug fusee replacement breaker" Several of the big box stores have them. Here is a link to the orange one.
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cooper-Bussmann-20-Amp-Plug-Type-Circuit-Breaker-BP-MB-20/100180284

The OP is talking about the fuse holder/socket, not the fuse itself.
